# UpdateProgress panel for Gridview behaves different for button vs linkbutton

Tags: gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, updateprogress

Howdy Fellow Stackoverflowians,

I'm seeing some odd behavior here and I'm hoping someone know a reason as to why.  If it matters I am using the AjaxControls for 3.5 not 4.0.

**Real basic set-up**; I have an UpdateProgress panel (with no associated control ID), and a gridview.   In a column of the gridview I have a asp:button defined as such;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGvEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("MyRecordID") %>' Text="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

I also added the default edit/cancel column LinkButton control in the typical manor from the Column Collection.  They both call the same function gvAppDeposit_RowEditing that just sets the edit index and rebinds the data to the grid;

```
gvAppDeposit.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
gvAppDeposit.DataSource =Dt
gvAppDeposit.DataBind()
```

Ok, now here is what I'm seeing; Clicking either the edit button or linkbutton, will both put the row in the edit state, with the cancel button now showing.  However, clicking on the edit button starts the UpdateProgress, but it never stops showing.  Clicking the edit linkbutton will also show the UpdateProgress panel, but it stops as expected.

Any idea how I can correct this behavior so that I can use buttons as opposed to link buttons?

Any info is GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this, for it's not at all related to what I've described above.  Because we use a FixFocus JS functionality to retain focus during ajax interactions it was causing the problems I described.   I fixed the JS and all is well with the world.